# How to rewrite this Java class to a Kotlin data class?

Tags: kotlin

I have this in Java :

```
public class User {

    String name;
    String id;
    int age;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(String id, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

In a Kotlin class its something like this :

```
class User {

    var name: String?=null
    var id: String?=null
    var age: Int = 0

    constructor(name: String) {
        this.name = name
    }

    constructor(name: String, id: String) {
        this.name = name
        this.id = id
    }

    constructor(id: String, age: Int) {
        this.id = id
        this.age = age
    }

    constructor() {}

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}'
    }
}
```

What I need to know, is how to do that in a data class with the 4 different constructors and the setters and getters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of default and named arguments, so there is no need for  multiple constructors. Define your data class like this:

```
data class User(var name: String? = null, var age: Int = 0, var id: String? = null)
```

And then construct it any number of ways.

```
User(name = "Foo") // returns User("Foo", 0, null)
User(name = "Foo", age = 21) // returns User("Foo", 21, null)
User(id = "x") // returns User(null, 0, "x")
User("Foo", 21, "x") // returns User("Foo", 21, "x")
User(id = "x", name = "Foo", age = 21) // returns User("Foo", 21, "x")
etc...
```

The getters and setters are defined for you, no need to define them either.

Comment: If I have the Java Class User, How I can use a User Java object to populate a new User Kotlin data class?

Answer (score 2):

Android studio provides an extremely simply method to achieve convert any Java class to Kotlin. Just type "convert java to kotlin" in your file search tab and the IDE will do that for you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin we can have that in a single constructor like this

```
data class User(var name: String, var age: Int = 0, var id: String = "ABC")
```

If we want to expose getters and not setters, we just provide **val** instead of **var** like below,

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int = 0, val id: String = "ABC")
```

getters/setters visibility modifiers we can provide them in the constructor like this,

```
data class User(internal val name, internal val age: Int = 0, internal var id: String = "ABC")
```

In this above case, getter will be accessible only to that module.

We can create object like this,

```
    var user = User("XYZ")
    var user1 = User("XYZ", 29)
    var user2 = User("XYZ", 29, "AXCVFC")
```

Answer (score 1):

just i added different answer from other's because if you have too many variable inside User data class then it should be too long like below.

```
 data class UserTooLongClass(var id: String, var name : String, var age : String, var location : String, var mobileNo : String, var mailId : String)
```

so you can create like below,

```
 data class User(var id: String = "1") {
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    var location : String = ""
    var mobileNo :  String = ""
    var mailId : String = ""

    override fun toString(): String {
        return " id : $id, name : $name, age : $age, location : $location, mobileNo : $mobileNo, mailId : $mailId"
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
val user : User = User()
    user.name = "TestName"
    user.id = "1223"
    user.age = 23
    user.mobileNo = "333"
    user.mailId = "ddd@gmail.com"
    user.location = "xxxxx"
    Log.d("TAG"," user : "+user.toString())
```

**Output :**

```
TAG:  user :  id : 1223, name : TestName, age : 23, location : xxxxx, mobileNo : 333, mailId : ddd@gmail.com
```